# Chrome extension that will search a webpage for strings with a specific format and highlight it

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I would like to have a Chrome extension (it can also be a Firefox addon) that will search a web page for a string with certain format (eg. if the format were ##-##-##### then it would highlight instances like 45-87-1417K or A4-22-G54DD) and highlight or change the backfround color for all the instances of strings with that format in the webpage.

I frequently work with a webpage that has a lot of numbers, but I only need to focus on those number with a specific format. With this addon I could ignore the rest of the rest of the information on the page.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question was asked several times on StackOverflow so you can find some of the existing answers. In short, you need a content script, and you can use an existing library *mark.js*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Chrome / Firefox do not see extension output in console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38913799/google-chrome-firefox-do-not-see-extension-output-in-console)